# is it possible to have 2 UICollectionViews under one controller and toggle between them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I posted this question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119494/what-is-the-best-way-to-dynamically-change-the-style-of-a-uicollectionview and received 0 responses.

I decided to experiment a bit. What I'm trying to do is have a grid style default collection view display change to a single file display when a UISegmentedControl is clicked.

**Grid style as default:**

[image]

**After tapping button left segment a single item view is displayed:**

[image]

I have a method ready that responds to the tap of each segment. I now hide the collectionView when the segment control is tapped and unhide it when it is tapped again.:

```
- (void)displayTypeSegmentSelected
{
    _selectedDisplayTypeIndex = [_displayTypeControl selectedSegmentIndex];

    if (_selectedDisplayTypeIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Single file item view selected");
        [_collectionView setHidden:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Grid style view selected");
        [_collectionView setHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

This works perfectly to show and hide my default collectionView and the functionality of the rest of this controller isn't affected.

**Possible solutions:**

Now I was wondering if there is a way to create another collectionView with the single file design and have it display whenever the default collectionView is hidden. It will use the exact same datasource and sort of plug in to the controller and just work.

**Can this be done view interface builder? If so how do I do this?**

**Can this be done programmatically? If so how do I go about doing this?**

I was wonder if I should have both collectionViews created initially rather than the default at the start and the single file only when segmentControl is clicked.

Would appreciate some examples or clear explanation. Been researching all day with no luck on how to do this.

Regards

Comment: Have you implemented successfully? Hi May I get any sample implementation for this: Github will work for new beginners like me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with two view controllers and toggle their position on the navigation stack.

However, for this special case I'd suggest using one view controller with two full-sized views and toggle their position within the view hierarchy of your topmost view or just hide and unhide the one on the top.

Comment: How would I add the second collectionView? Possible in IB? or would it have to be programmatically?

Comment: It is possible in IB per drag & drop. Programmatically you could use `self.secondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];` in `viewDidLoad`. However, in most cases using bounds is saver than frame. Here it shoud work.

Comment: Hi May I get any sample implementation for this: Github will work for new beginners like me.

Comment: @Meenu, I am afraid I don't have any. Frankly, I never did that myself. However, it is dead easy. You have one view controller with one basic view, the very self.view. Then you use either IB (storyboard editor) to create view1 and view2, or you create them programmatically. But create properties in your view controller and set/connect them so that you can address them with self.view1 and self.view2. Both have share the same frame as self.view, meaning the cover all of the screen that is available. (cont ...)

Comment: ... (cont) Make self.view1 subview of self.view and make self.view2 subview of self.view2. OR make both subviews of self.view but add self.view1 first. Now self.view2 is visible. And only self.view2 is visible. Now, instead of toggeling between the views, just hide self.view2. `[self.view2 setHidden = YES]` And later, when required, unhide it again. Really, it is that easy.

Comment: I am trying this around 2 days , as i am being in need to load hell lot of images with high resolution , scroll view appending images , labels , keeping two views (though hidden) etc eating memory more. so memory warning coming. Also , how to keep scroll index common for both views ? I am not using table view , collection view. Just a view and adding to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same collection view but only change the data source and delegate.